# HTML textbox not working in AngularJS directive template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've made a small directive for my AngularJS application, here is the directive template:

```
    <div style="width:100px; height:30px; background-color:white;">
<div style="background-color:khaki; width:100%; height:30px; text-align:center;"  >
<span ng-if="show_label" ng-dblclick="ChangeTitle($event)">{{ GetTitle() }}</span>
<textarea style="z-index:1000000"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div style="width:100px; height:120px; background-color:skyblue;" >
            <div style="height:24px; width:24px; background-color:orange; position:relative; top:50px; left:50px;
z-index:2000; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;" ng-click="SwitchRoot()" onclick="SwitchRoot2()"></div>

    </div>
```

I have a small problem: my text area (or text box) doesn't receive any input, meaning that I cannot type anything in the textbox!

what is the problem? what is going wrong here?

Comment: can you create a plunker which repos this?

Comment: what do you need to know? is anything missing?

Comment: I think we need more. I [fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/suudpjk0/) this and I can type. Just guessing there is more to it than this

Comment: Yes I suppose you are right, the whole project is a lot bigger, I'm uploading it in a server, and will give you the link in a few minutes...

Comment: http://www.silverlight4web.com/fw/index.html

Comment: Please view it in FireFox, from the left toolbar, click on the flowchart (most bottom item), then click again in the white area in the center. Then click again on the bottom item (Flowchart) and click on the white area (which now should be bigger), you'll see this directive, but the textbox cannot get focus.

Comment: Please show us your js code, not just html template